# Reading Post request body containing form data file in TYPO3/PHP sent from Angular

Tags: php, angular, upload, typo3

I'm trying to upload an image from Angular to TYPO3 backend and I'm failing to read the request body in the Controller.

Here's my code on the Angular side:

1. Html:

```html
<input multiple type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)" />
```

2. Typescript:

```js
uploadFile(event:any){
    const file:File = event.target.files[0];
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('filename', 'myimage');
    formData.append('file', file);
    
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' ,
        });
    
    this.http.post(`<serverurl>/fileupload/upload/`, formData, {headers:headers});
}
```

I've tried PHP ways to read the file such as using

- `$_FILES` or
- `$_POST`

and they both failed. Then I've tried this:

Typo3:
`FileUploadController`:

```php
public function uploadAction(){
 $request = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']->getBody()->__toString();
}
```

and I was able to read the request payload as string but I can't parse it.

Is there a TYPO3-way to get the image file from the post request?

Comment: Do not set the `Content-Type` header yourself, there is a good chance because of that the necessary `boundary` information is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $request = json_decode($GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']->getBody()->__toString());
```

This should do the trick. Feels a bit hacky though, a better solution would be nice. ;-)